# Canvas renderer not working

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

Trying to test my app using canvasrenderer as a fallback to webgl, but it occurs i can't start it properly?

```
renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
console.log('renderer', renderer);
renderer.sortObjects = true
renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff );
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

I have included the

```
CanvasRenderer.js
```

from examples. It throws an error from CanvasRenderer.js

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

at line 83, which is:

```
_v5 = new THREE.RenderableVertex(),
```

Comment: Is there any error in the console?

Comment: no. just the one saying that canvas renderer was moved to examples, but this error is coded into three as I found on github

Comment: is blank white or black , also set your css bg for body to red or green...so you could see if it loads the renderer at all or just fails

Comment: @Careen switched the background to green. Doesn't load it at all

Comment: ok so we know that much... can you get a js fiddle going or a bin paste so i can simulate the issue here

Comment: @Careen got some path problems blah...but now the renderer throws error. Check question edit

Comment: , im thinking you have two versions running example , canvas rendere v62 and three.js  66 did you get both from the same package if you understand what im getting at... what version you using now?

Comment: im using the most up to date version from github. both threejs and renderer from examples

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77182/discussion-between-careen-and-mjanisz1).

Comment: Yeah continue the discussion in chat and please don't even bother posting any result here, that is clearly not the point of SO.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need canvas renderer if you are using the newest THREE.JS. I have been using CanvasRenderer without the canvasrenderer js file. Maybe you can try to remove the canvasrenderer.js?